# .map dont show list (from API)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

thanks in advance!!
I'm in trouble, I dont know whats wrong with my map hehe. I'm a new student (JS, React, Redux). It'd should show a list (or at least one name, anything), but nothing happen.

```
 import React, {Component} from "react";
    import { connect } from "react-redux";
    import { push } from "connected-react-router";
    import { getTrips } from "../../actions/allActions";
    import List from "@material-ui/core/List";

    class ListTrips extends Component {
        componentDidMount() {
          this.props.getTripsAction();
        }

        render() {
          return (
              <List>
                  {
                      this.props.trips.map((trip) => {
                          return(<li>{trip.name}</li>)
                      })
                  }
              </List>
          );
      }
    }

      const mapStateToProps = state => ({
        trips: state.trips.trips
      });

      const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
        getTripsAction: () => dispatch(getTrips()),

      });

      export default connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        mapDispatchToProps
      )(ListTrips)
```

Comment: What's the code that creates a `ListTrips`?

Comment: console.log(this.props.trips) at the start of render method and check

Comment: Also don't forget to assign a `key` to your `<li>` tags so React can track them.
https://medium.com/@nothingisfunny/keys-and-refs-in-react-fd954457fd75

Comment: What does it show instead? If you inspect the element in your browser's developer tools, what is actually rendered as HTML?

Comment: Soon I'm gonna try everything u suggested me, thank all you =)

Comment: Peoople!! problem solved! I just changed my reducer, in a simple way, it was very confused, now it's working =) the console.log(this.props.trips) helps me see it